# How do I place an image icon in a sentence so that it flows like a character?

Tags: html, css

I have the sentence "Click on the 'Learn more" buttons for additional information" and I'm trying to put an (i) information icon right before "Learn more" but I can't seem to get it right. It's appearing on top of the words Learn more.

Can anyone help?

Edit: Sorry, here is my code:

Click on the "Learn More" buttons throughout the exercise to get additional information specific to each service.

and before "Learn More" there is my image:

```
<img id="learn" src="http://public.citizenbudget.com.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/custom/london/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-01%20at%202.41.23%20PM.png" width="20">
```

and then in CSS I used:

```
#learn {
 position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using? Otherwise, nobody's likely to be able to guess why your attempt isn't working the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try and use `display: inline` on your `img` element like:

```
<p>
Some text with an image here <img style='display:inline;' src='blah.jpg'/>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>Learn More<img style="display: inline;" src="http://public.citizenbudget.com.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/custom/london/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-01%20at%202.41.23%20PM.png" width="23px" height="23px"> </p>
```

Comment: I'd recommend to delete that "position: absolute;"

Answer (score 0):

Try "display: inline;"
That should display the image with the flow of the text but show us your code I'm sure we will able to get it to work

Edit: You wouldn't need position: absolute, unless you wanted to move that icon anywhere you wanted, so try it with just the "display: inline"
Also insert the image tags inside of the p tags

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it didn't work. I placed the img in a div with the id="learn" instead of id-ing the img but also not working.

Comment: It did! Thank you very much.